# How to make Fn(T) + 'static register as 'static for any generic type argument T?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm using the [specs crate](https://crates.io/crates/specs) which has a `Component` trait which extends the `std::any::Any` trait (the `Any` trait just requires `'static`). I want to include a `Box<Fn(T) + 'static>` field (with generic argument `T`) in a struct for which `Component` is implemented, which means `Box<Fn(T) + 'static>` needs to be `'static`. That means I need `Fn(T) + 'static` to be `'static` for any `T`.

It seems `Fn(T) + 'static` is not `'static` for any generic type argument `T`. `T` could refer to a struct with its own lifetimes, but I expected it not to be a problem because there is no instance of a reference with those lifetimes in the `Fn` to make the `Fn` itself not `'static` - those lifetimes are only in the arguments passed to the `Fn`, but it is as if `Fn(T) + 'static` is considered to contain a `T` itself.

Example:

```
struct HandlesT<T> {
    handler: Box<Fn(T) + 'static>,
}

impl<T> HandlesT<T> {
    pub fn new<F: Fn(T) + 'static>(handler: F) -> HandlesT<T> {
        HandlesT {
            handler: Box::new(handler),
        }
    }
}

trait IsStatic: 'static {}
impl<T> IsStatic for HandlesT<T> {}
```

```
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:14:9
   |
14 | impl<T> IsStatic for HandlesT<T> {}
   |      -  ^^^^^^^^
   |      |
   |      help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...
   |
note: ...so that the type `HandlesT<T>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:14:9
   |
14 | impl<T> IsStatic for HandlesT<T> {}
   |         ^^^^^^^^
```

In the example, since `HandlesT<T>` contains no non-static references at all for any given `T` (no references at all except those owned by the `Fn`, but those must be `'static`), I expected `HandlesT<T>` to be static for any `T`, but the error indicates that it is not.

The compiler suggestion to "consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`" neither supports any generic type argument T, nor provides hints as to why `HandlesT<T>` for any generic `T` is not `'static`, given that `HandlesT<T>` would not contain a `T`.

Example of `T: 'static` (the compiler's suggestion) not supporting any generic `T`, in this case `&'a i32`:

```
struct HandlesT<T: 'static> {
    handler: Box<Fn(T) + 'static>,
}

impl<T: 'static> HandlesT<T> {
    pub fn new<F: Fn(T) + 'static>(handler: F) -> HandlesT<T> {
        HandlesT {
            handler: Box::new(handler),
        }
    }
}

trait IsStatic: 'static {}
impl<T: 'static> IsStatic for HandlesT<T> {}

fn try_nonstatic_t<'a>() {
    let handles_t = HandlesT {
        handler: Box::new(|i: &'a i32| {}),
    };
}
```

```
error[E0477]: the type `&'a i32` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src\lib.rs:17:21
   |
17 |     let handles_t = HandlesT {
   |                     ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: type must satisfy the static lifetime
```

Comment: Seems that this may have come up on Reddit once, some time ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6d9xaw/how_do_i_express_that_im_not_storing_argument/

Comment: After a long discussion on Discord, this resulted in this issue being submitted: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57325

If it turns out to be a bug in Rust, I'll remove this comment and make it the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A discussion on discord about this yielded [Issue 57325](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57325) and the discussion there seems to have left things in a state of:

- It's not logically correct ("language wart")
- Backwards compatibility may make fixing it impossible
- Would probably require an RFC to fix, it was closed as "working as expected for now"
- See [RFC 1214](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1214-projections-lifetimes-and-wf.md) for justification of why it is implemented the way it is today.